# Page loading Progress Bar on WordPress like Youtube/Google

Tags: php, html

I need to create a progress bar to showing the loading of any pages on a WordPress website.
I know how to use the  HTML tag or use jQuery ProgressBar but I can't understand how to implement it in php creating e realtime loading progress bar.
The similar progressbar is on Google/Youtube.
Now I found Pace.js script but I'm not sure it's a realtime loading progressbar.
Please Anyone could help me?

Thanks in advance